# Huge size difference between app bundles build by pure react native & expo bare workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

I have build two app bundles for same application by pure react native (version 0.66) and expo bare workflow (expo eject, expo version: 42.0.1, react-native version: 0.63.4 )

| Build by | App bundle size (mb) |
| --- | --- |
| Pure react native | 29 |
| Expo bare (eject) | 14 |

There is a huge size difference (15 mb) between two app bundles.

When I looked into app bundles for my device I found that `config.arm64_v8a.apk` has two different sizes.

| Build by | `config.arm64_v8a.apk`(mb) | base.apk(mb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pure react native | 18.2 | 12.2 |
| Expo bare (eject) | 11.5 | 12.7 |

I couldn't find out why `config.arm64_v8a.apk` has two file sizes in these two flows.

Why expo bare workflow app bundle is so small ? Is this because currently expo use react-native 0.63.4 or does expo has some additional app bundle size reducing method(s) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Expo has recently published a blog post about app bundling.

> bundle sizes are also smaller by about 18% in “Hello World” apps. This is because many libraries are already shipped in an optimal format, and by needlessly transforming them with a random Babel cocktail, we increase the size, but only a little bit, and everywhere.

I think it's an interesting read (and good source!) for what you're looking for:
https://blog.expo.dev/drastically-faster-bundling-in-react-native-a54f268e0ed1

Answer (score 0):

Put android:extractNativeLibs="true" into the AndroidManifest.xml under application tag